# How can i make my OSX desktop application build?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm new in the mac application development,  the thing I've tried is to copy UDID from system report and add it to the developer account (MAC portion), [image]

then after I'm creating Distribution Profile and installing it,
now the thing is in cocoa Application project, under product folder, i'm archiving the certain build and sharing it with my another desktop, but it's not working, any suggestion? how can I make an application which is compatible with every version of MAC-OS . . .

Comment: Your explanation has a few holes in it; Can you show pictures of you project settings? What export options do you select after Build ▶ Archive is successful? (Do you want to make an app that can be downloaded from your website or submit to the App Store?)

Comment: for example in mobile application [iOS], what I do to make build is simply build the project [in Build only Device] . and then from the "Products" folder I archive that .app file and upload it to the Diawi [this build can install all the devices which have been added to our profile ] , but now what about mac application ? the same process isn't working

Comment: You don't need the Mac UUID anywhere Please add the screenshots as requested for further debugging ideas.